# Wordpress Elementor reCAPTCHA multiple site keys

Tags: wordpress, recaptcha, elementor

First off, I'm a Wordpress novice. I've been drafted to do some work on my employer's company website because I'm a techie.

We have an Elementor form where someone requests an account. On submit, a request is sent to a REST API to store the request and send out emails for approval. More happens after that, but it's not pertinent to my question.

On the Wordpress site, we have a production form for requesting an account and a copy of that for testing. We do changes on the test version and then roll those over to production when they are working.

We are adding reCAPTCHA v2 to the form. On Google, I want to set up one configuration for testing and another for production. This is what Google recommends and it make perfect sense. But that means I have two different site keys that I need to put into the Elementor settings. It appears there is no way to do this. Elementor only has a place for one set of keys.

We need to be able to have the production form in production while adding new functionality to the test version. The test version will use a development/test version of the REST API.

Is there a way to do this? I'd hate to scrap Elementor. But that might be my only option.